# Algorithm that gets latest inputs in database based on two different factors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a website build upon laravel. The website consist of users, and users can follow each other. `Users` can make `Shoutouts` (like a tweet), and the users that are following each other should be able to see these. I have a `User` table in my database, and a `Shoutout` table, and a `Follow` table.

As it is made i Laravel, the User has a `hasMany` relationship to both the Shoutout and the Follow table.

So when a user logs in, I want to get all the people that the User is following. This i do by the following:

```
$following = Follow::whereUser_id($user->id)->get();
```

However, how would I now get the `Shoutouts` from the users in `$following`, in an order descending from the time the shoutout was created, so I can do a foreach($shoutouts as $shoutout) in my view? 
The ideas is that the User can see the latest Shoutouts from the people that the user is following.

If i did something like:

```
$following = Follow::whereUser_id($user->id)->get();

foreach($following as $follow) {
    $shoutouts = $shoutouts . Shoutout::whereUser_id($follow->user_id)->get();
}
```

I would get them in an incorrect order, as this would give me all the shoutouts of a specific user right after each other, but I would like to get them in descending order, so the user sees the latest shoutouts first.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Just write direct query for that

DB::table('users')
->join('follow', 'users.id', '=', 'follow.user_id')
->join('shoutout', 'follow.followed_user_id', '=', 'shoutout.user_id')
->orderBy('shoutout.date', 'desc')
->get()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it by using [`join`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) as:

Assuming you have a `followed_user_id` in your `Follow` table.

```
$shoutouts = Shoutout::join('follow', 'shoutout.user_id', '=', 'follow.followed_user_id')
                    ->where('follow.user_id', $user->id)
                    ->select(''shoutout.*'')
                    ->orderBy('shoutout.created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get()
```

Comment: Hi Amit, and thanks again for your help! This worked like a charm! How long have you been working with laravel?

Comment: Happy to help :D. It's been six months and I really loved it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading on your followed user's shoutouts.  If you have your relationships defined correctly you should be able to do:

```
$following = Follow::whereUser_id($user->id)->with('shoutouts')->get();
```

Then access the shoutouts by user with:

```
foreach($following as $follow) {
    $shoutouts = $follow->shoutouts;
    //Do Something With The Collection Of Shoutouts
}
```

**UPDATE**
To get just the shoutouts of users they follow you would define a `hasManyThrough` on your user table:

```
public function followerShoutouts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Shoutout::class, Follow::class, 'user_id', 'user_id_being_followed');
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$shoutouts = User::with(['followerShoutouts' => function($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->find($userId);
```

Comment: How would this address the problem of getting the "shoutouts" in the correct order? Wouldn't this still be grouped by followed users with no regard to the most recent "shoutout"?

Comment: You are correct.  Updated the example with a relation that will give you the shoutouts as long as that `user_id_being_followed` is updated with your actual column name from the `follows` table